# Как пакетно удалить watermark c изображения?

Tags: python, watermark

Есть большое количество картинок с Watermark-oм, нужно автоматически их почистить. Картинки разных размеров, вотермарки имеют разный размер и по разному разбросаны по картинке. Примерно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел на Python:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('/content/5.jpg')
mask = cv.imread('/content/5dd7e0889d9e4.png',0)
dst = cv.inpaint(img,mask,3,1)
cv.imwrite("cleaned.png", dst)
```

Но здесь надо чтобы была маска файла где нужно почистить, с такими же размерами как сам файл и уже выделенными областями где чистить.
Подскажите решение или где и куда копать?

Comment: если ватермарка полупрозрачная и лежит на тексте (желательно цветном и ватермарка желательно цветная) то фиг вы ее всю вычистите, особенно если изображение в jpg

Comment: Ватермарка не цветная - черная, нигде не перекрывает основной текст.

Comment: но в jpeg она будет все равно не соответствовать шаблону и вам надо будет какое-то нечёткое сравнение

Comment: @Zhihar, `если ватермарка полупрозрачная и лежит на тексте (желательно цветном и ватермарка желательно цветная) то фиг вы ее всю вычистите` - где-то я наталкивался на статью о `DCGAN (deep convolutional generative adversarial networks)` в которой решалась очень похожая задача, но врядли сейчас смогу найти...